# how to combine multiple recycler views with a scroll vertically in 1 linear layout

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to use 2 recycler views in 1 linear layout.
A recycler view will generate its own scroll but other data remains intact on the screen, so how do I combine everything into 1 scrolling area?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:weightSum="100">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliderhome"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="70">


                <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                    android:id="@+id/slider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    />
                <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="30"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:context="vlabs.chorbazaar.HomeFragment"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying to make my slider and recycler view to scroll as one, but the slider is stuck at a constant place while the recycler view scrolls as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/grey"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:weightSum="100">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliderhome"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="70">


    <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        />
    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

viewpager adapter:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> arrayList ) {
        super(fm);
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

        case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance(arraylist);
        case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance(arraylist);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }       
}
```

}

in activty:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), arrayList));
```

fragment in xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: im using fragments.. so suppose the above code was my home frag.. i changed my home frag xml as you said.. made a class for Mypageadapter.. ok done.. 

now ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), arrayList));
were will this code go ? in my main activity where i have all fragments called based on selection in nav

Comment: and what is the arraylist ??

Comment: arrayList in data send for Fragment                    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayFirst = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayFirst.add("one");
        arrayFirst.add("two");
        
        ArrayList<String> arraySound = new ArrayList<>();
        arraySound.add("three");
        arraySound.add("four");


        arrayList.add(arrayFirst);
        arrayList.add(arraySound);

Comment: change @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

        case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance(arraylist.get(pos));
        case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance(arraylist.get(pos));
    }

Comment: thank you it worked ..
i just disabled the recycler view scroll and made it clickable.. n kept eveything in scroll view n done... 4 lines of code n done but still thnks for your help